# Velo Website button not opening dynamic link in new tab

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a button which extracts a web link from a CMS entry on click. This entry is selected based on the user email of the logged in user. This is working fine, CMS connection ok and correct data extracted (I am printing this out on the text fields). I then want to open this link in a new tab but this does not open. I have checked that the links are fine and no error messages are in the log.

Code attached.

The issues lies in
$w('#button3').link = entry.link;

FYI the window.open option isn't working for me either as "cannot find name 'window'".

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {

    async function button3_click(event) {
        let user = wixUsers.currentUser;
        let userEmail;

        if (user.loggedIn) {
            try {
                // Get the user's email using async/await
                userEmail = await user.getEmail();
                console.log('user email', userEmail);
                $w('#text51').text = userEmail;

                // Query CMS collection based on the user's email
                wixData.query('ExceldocumentLinks')
                    .eq('email', userEmail)
                    .find()
                    .then(results => {
                        // Check if any entries were found
                        if (results.items.length > 0) {
                            console.log('got here 2');
                            // Access the first entry
                            const entry = results.items[0];


                // Open the link
                            $w('#button3').link = entry.link;

                        } else {
                            // Handle the case where no entry was found for the constant email value
                            console.error('No CMS entry found for the constant email value');
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Handle errors during the query
                        console.error('Error querying CMS:', error);
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error getting user email:', error);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the user is not logged in
            console.error('User not logged in');
        }
    }

    // Assign the click event handler to the button
    $w('#button3').onClick(button3_click);
});
```